# Data saved locally but not on server using socket io and node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have run this code on locally. It saves messages in database but now i am trying to run this code on server side. It can't save messages on db.

Receive message function works fine but `save_new_message` function not working. I don't know its a port issue or something else.

```
 /**
     * method to check if u receive a new message
     */

    socket.on('new_message', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('new_message', {
            messageId: data.messageId,
            senderImage: data.senderImage,
            senderId: data.senderId,
            recipientId: data.recipientId,
            senderName: data.senderName,
            messageBody: data.messageBody,
            date: data.date,
            isGroup: data.isGroup,
            conversationId: data.conversationId,
            image: data.image,
            video: data.video,
            audio: data.audio,
            document: data.document,
            thumbnail: data.thumbnail,
            phone: data.phone
        });
    });

    /**
     * method to save new message to database
     */
    socket.on('save_new_message', function (data) {
        saveMessageToDataBase(data);
    });
    /**
     * method to save message of user
     * @param data
     */
    function saveMessageToDataBase(data) {
        var http = require('http');
        var queryString = require("querystring");
        var qs = queryString.stringify(data);
        var qslength = qs.length;
        var path = require('path').basename(__dirname);
        var hostname = os.hostname();
        var options = {
            hostname: hostname,
            port: mainPort,
            path: '/' + path + '/Messages/send',
            method: 'POST',
            type: "json",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': qslength
            }
        };

        var buffer = "";
        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                buffer += chunk;
            });

            res.on('error', function (e) {
                console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
            });
        });

        req.write(qs);
        req.end();

    }
```

Comment: Where is the part when you save it in database?

Comment: saveMessageToDataBase is a function that save value in db..

Comment: But this function is not saving into db, it is sending data to some API.

Comment: check email bro and reply plz

Comment: I am happy to help you out. But you need to post your code where you are facing the problem. Without looking at your code, I can't guess what could be wrong.